# How to get the directory path where a Batch file is called from?

Tags: windows-10, batch, cmd.exe, window

If you put a `test.bat` file in your desktop of your Windows 10 machine, then you can call it by simply writing `test` in the address bar of Windows directory explorer.

This behavior is used by `cmd` command to start a command line in any custom directory as  described [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/139900/stupid-geek-tricks-run-commands-in-the-windows-explorer-address-bar/).

Now that my `test.bat` is working like `cmd` I want to know where my batch file is called from. I mean the directory where the `test` command is invoked in it's address bar.

Comment: Would `%CD%` help? Look at [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17064031/117259) for more details.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 %CD% is the same as using cd and it shows your current directory, not the script's folder. If the script is in a directory included in the %path% setting, the wrong path is returned. See my answer for the correct way to do it.

Comment: @LPChip Good answer! Linux and macOS user here so just posted as a comment because I really don’t know for sure, so better suggest than insist! Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Batch scripts have a few variables they can use to get special information about the script.

`%1` to `%9` are the parameters that were used after calling the batch script, but `%0` is the full path including the filename itself of the batch file.

So if the batchfile is stored on the desktop, `%0` would be:

```
c:\users\user\Desktop\test.bat
```

Given that `%0` gives us this information, we can use special operators to extract the path.

The variable you are looking for is `%~dp0`.

In order to store this in a variable and work with it later, you can use the following command:

```
set scriptpath=%~dp0
echo %scriptpath%   :: will output c:\users\user\Desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

He was looking to determine the directory where the batch file was called, not the directory of the batch file. your answer is like %CD%, not valid in this case.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).